# Excel formula, find the first instance of OU= in string and remove any characters before it

Tags: excel

I have 1000's of strings similar to "CN=Joe Smith,OU=Students,DC=Domain,DC=Edu" and I want to find the first instance of OU= and remove the characters before it leaving me with "OU=Students,DC=Domain,DC=Edu". How can I do this with an Excel formula?

Many thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("OU=",A1)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined jevakallio's answer with [How do I recognize “#VALUE!” in Excel spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689235/how-do-i-recognize-value-in-excel-spreadsheets) for cases when the key "OU=" doesn't exist in the cell.

Situations:

```
CN=Joe Smith,OU=Students,DC=Domain,DC=Edu
CN=Jane Doe,DC=Domain,DC=Edu
```

Right Value checking for missing key:

```
=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("OU=",A2)+1)),"OU= Not Found",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("OU=",A2)+1))
```

Results:

```
OU=Students,DC=Domain,DC=Edu
OU= Not Found
```