# How do I recognize "#VALUE!" in Excel spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to write a formula such that if cell A1 displays `#VALUE!`, say `TRUE` in cell B1.

Here's my formula in cell B1:

```
=IF(A1="#VALUE!", "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

I get `FALSE` when A1 does not say `#VALUE!` so that part is fine.  But, when it does say `#VALUE!`, I get a `#VALUE!` error in cell B1, when I want it to say `TRUE`.  How do I do this?

Comment: Forgot to mention, the #VALUE error in cell A1 is caused by another formula...and I'm not trying to look for a string "#VALUE".

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Use `IFERROR(value, value_if_error)`

Comment: does exactly what i wanted, thanks!  i chose your answer since you were correct & first in line.

Comment: Haha thanks, ninja typing skills if a bit thin on the examples

Answer (score 48):

This will return `TRUE` for `#VALUE!` errors (ERROR.TYPE = 3) and `FALSE` for anything else.

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1),ERROR.TYPE(A1)=3)
```

Comment: +1.  Worth pointing out that this one will work in versions before XL 2007 and, since it targets only #VALUE!, will avoid masking other errors.  Interesting discussion of IFERROR here: http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/04/18/is-iferror-bad/

Answer (score 0):

in EXCEL 2013 i had to use IF function 2 times:
1st to identify error with ISERROR
and 2nd to identify the specific type of error by ERROR.TYPE=3 in order to address this type of error. This way you can differentiate between error you want and other types.