# How to capture #REF! in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to know how to capture the `#REF!` error in Excel.

I am able to catch error in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) with the following code :

```
    If WorksheetFunction.IsError(ActiveCell) Then
         If ActiveCell.Value = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then
              ActiveCell.Value = "Error"
         End If
   End If
```

I would like to write the same function in Excel Formula Bar. Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You may need to combine the `IsError` formula with the `IsRef` formula. See my suggestion below.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10689580/657668

Answer (score 3):

You can use ISERROR in the formula bar and check if true or false

this works to identify only isref errors
=IFERROR(IF(ERROR.TYPE(A1)=4,"Ref Error",A1),"All GOOD")

Comment: Well, ISERROR() will catch all the errors. I would like to catch on #REF!

Comment: Try to do something with this =ERROR.TYPE(#REF!)

Comment: ok here you go --- =IF(ERROR.TYPE(A1)=4,"Error","All good") .. if error type is #ref then "error" else "all good"

Comment: Except Error.Type will return N/A if there is no error in the cell.

Comment: Another wrinkle for OP -- and perhaps this doesn't matter -- is that formula can contain multiple error conditions, but the cell value will only display the first error encountered. E.g., `=SheetDoesNotExist!A1+badname` will give a `#Ref!` error, while `=badName+SheetDoesNotExist!A1` will give a `#Name?` error.

Answer (score 2):

**Note** that the cell will only return the *first* error encountered when evaluating a formula, so if a cell has a `#Name?` error that occurs before a `#Ref!` error, there is no way to trap the potential `#Ref!` error.

Maybe something like:

`=AND(ISREF(A1),ISERR(A1))`

First test whether the cell contains a REFERENCE and then check to see if it also contains an error.

I revise to use `IsErr` instead of `IsError` to ignore `N/A` type errors.

Comment: You can have ref and a different kind of error in the same formula.  Consider `=B5+badname`

Answer (score 2):

`=IF(ISERROR(A1),ERROR.TYPE(#REF!)=ERROR.TYPE(A1),FALSE)`

Returns true on #ref, false on all other errors or no error.

Comment: You could use 4 in place of ERROR.TYPE(#REF!), but I think this makes it clearer what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula `IF(ISERROR(ActiveCell),"Error")`

This will however, catch all other errors as well.

Comment: Yes, You are right. However, I want to catch only the #REF! error