# Evaluate() Function Returning Error 2023, however there is no error

Tags: excel, vba, function, evaluate

I am using the `Evaluate() function` to test a value for errors prior to placing into a cell.  In my example below, this is returning `Error 2023`, However when I paste the string into a cell, it reads correctly with no error (will return exactly the value referenced in the external spreadsheet).  The example is as follows:

```
Evaluate("='H:\@Projects\@Dev[BudgetTracking_ProjectName_MSTR_FK_2.xlsm]Budget Estimate (2)'!F44")
```

Comment: If this is a followup question to [Determine if formula will return #Ref! error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28038285/445425) then use of `Evaluate` where the formula you want to test refers to a closed workbook will not work.  An alternative might be to use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and just write the formula to the cell then test for `#Ref!`.  This will suppress to File Open dialog.   (Remember to `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after)

Comment: That is a great approach, Chris. The function does work, but there is another handling tier of this thing that I need to work the logic out for and this suggestion I think will be really useful.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error 2023 is the `xlErrRef` `#REF!`. The Evaluate function can't directly evaluate from closed workbooks. Open the `H:\@Projects\@Dev\BudgetTracking_ProjectName_MSTR_FK_2.xlsm` and

```
Evaluate("='H:\@Projects\@Dev\[BudgetTracking_ProjectName_MSTR_FK_2.xlsm]Budget Estimate (2)'!F44")
```

will work. Note the "\" behind the directory name "@Dev".

But then of course

```
Evaluate("='[BudgetTracking_ProjectName_MSTR_FK_2.xlsm]Budget Estimate (2)'!F44")
```

will suffice.

To get values from closed workbooks you have to use an Excel4Macro functionality. See: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/