# How can I convert the date column to a different builtin date type in excel (Thu Aug 04 00:00:00 BST 1983)

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have an excel file in which the dob column contains entry of this type `Thu Aug 04 00:00:00 BST 1983`. I am trying to import the excel file in SQL-Server therefore I want to convert it to `YYYY-MM-DD` type. I tried the format cells option but it is not working. Any simple way of doing it or do I have to find regex for it?

Here is the sample file.

[image]

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your string in excel is `Thu Aug 04 00:00:00 BST 1983` with the same format, then you can try this:

[image: Excel Example]

Then goto Custom format cells and select `Date` first and then select `Custom` and type `YYYY-MM-DD` to get the desired format.

Comment: Just to add that the column B in above case must be date type to work it properly.

Comment: Do you know how can I replace #VALUE! with blank as formula output. I tried IFERROR(formula, 0) but it is not working

Comment: @Asbat: I guess you are asking about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689235/how-do-i-recognize-value-in-excel-spreadsheets

Comment: Thanks. I used it wrong first I tried =IFERROR(Your_formula, 0) where as the correct one is =IFERROR(Your_formula, "")

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel's `DATE()` function to do this. This takes year, month and day as values. There is some manipulation required to your date to get these values.

Please see below. 3rd row shows values: `30532` becomes `1983-08-04` when it is formatted (show formulae is on so you can see 2nd row)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it not possible to do it in one formula (combine them) because there are a lot of columns with similar date type and it will be a bit tedious to split each of them in year, month and day column and then combine them.

Comment: It is; replace `B2`,`C2` and `D2` in cell `E2` with the equations in those cells. This becomes `=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),MONTH(DATEVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,7),3)&"1")),RIGHT(LEFT(A2,10),2))`